# Проверка HWID при авторизации C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Хочу сделать в программе чтобы при авторизации проверялся HWID, но не понял как это можно реализовать.

В данный момент авторизация выглядит так

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String loginUser = loginField.Text;
    String passUser = passField.Text;

    DB db = new DB();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @uL AND `pass` = @uP", db.getConnection());
    command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
    command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(table);

    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Авторизован");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Пароль или логин указан не верно");
}
```

Comment: Совсем никаких мыслей? В коде не видно вашей попытки это реализовать. Или не работает, или что такое HWID в вашем понимании? Откуда вы взяли эту идею? Какую именно задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Я не понимаю как реализовать это и хотел спросить у людей, хотелось бы при авторизации на сервер проверялось HWID и если HWID совпал то авторизировал пользователя, а если не совпал то выходило окошко с ошибкой

Comment: MAC адрес сетевухи тоже HWID, что именно вы имеете в виду под этой аббревиатурой?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2333172/12888024

Comment: ЖД компуктера имею ввиду под HWID. Номер жесткого диска

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4084543/12888024